# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request is already handled

Tags: node.js, express, puppeteer

So i have this nodejs that was originaly used as api to crawl data using puppeteer from a website based on a schedule, now to check if there is a schedule i used a function that link to a model query and check if there are any schedule at the moment.
It seems to work and i get the data, but when i was crawling the second article and the next there is always this error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request is already handled!` and followed by `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().`
and it seems to take a lot of resource from the cpu and memory.
So my question is, is there any blocking in my code or anything that could have done better.

this is my server.js

```
function mydbqueryarticle(callback) {
    News.findNullArticle(function(err, article) {
        if(article!=null){
            console.log('Crawling');
            Crawl.article(err)
        }else{
            console.log('No article to crawl');
        }
    })  
    callback();
}

function wait10sec(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        mydbqueryarticle(wait10sec);
    }, 10000);
}

wait10sec();
```

This is my news model

```
News.findNullArticle = function (result) {
    dbConn.query("SELECT id, source, keyword, title, link from article where article_status = 0 ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT 1", function (err, res) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("error: ", err);
            result(null, err);
        }
        else{
            console.log('article : ', res);
            result(null, res[0]);
        }
    });
};
```

And this is my crawl controller

```
function crawl_article(news_id, news_link, all_page_tag, body_article, article_date, article_el, article_tag_el) {
    try {
        (async () => {

            // Add stealth plugin and use defaults (all tricks to hide puppeteer usage)
            const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
            puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())
            // Add adblocker plugin to block all ads and trackers (saves bandwidth)
            const AdblockerPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker')
            puppeteer.use(AdblockerPlugin({ blockTrackers: true }))

            puppeteer.launch({
                headless: true,
                executablePath: '/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome',
                args: ['--autoplay-policy=user-gesture-required',
                '--disable-background-networking',
                '--disable-background-timer-throttling',
                '--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows',
                '--disable-breakpad',
                '--disable-client-side-phishing-detection',
                '--disable-component-update',
                '--disable-default-apps',
                '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
                '--disable-domain-reliability',
                '--disable-extensions',
                '--disable-features=AudioServiceOutOfProcess',
                '--disable-hang-monitor',
                '--disable-ipc-flooding-protection',
                '--disable-notifications',
                '--disable-offer-store-unmasked-wallet-cards',
                '--disable-popup-blocking',
                '--disable-print-preview',
                '--disable-prompt-on-repost',
                '--disable-renderer-backgrounding',
                '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
                '--disable-speech-api',
                '--disable-sync',
                '--hide-scrollbars',
                '--ignore-gpu-blacklist',
                '--metrics-recording-only',
                '--mute-audio',
                '--no-default-browser-check',
                '--no-first-run',
                '--no-pings',
                '--no-sandbox',
                '--no-zygote',
                '--password-store=basic',
                '--use-gl=swiftshader',
                '--use-mock-keychain'] 
            }).then(async browser => {
                console.log(news_link);
                const page = await browser.newPage();
                await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
                await page.goto(news_link+all_page_tag);
                await page.waitForSelector('body');
                await autoScroll(page);
                //await page.waitForTimeout(2500);

                let current_time = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                var rposts = await page.evaluate((body_article, article_date, article_el, article_tag_el) => {
                    let get_article_date, get_article, get_tag;
                    let posts = document.body.querySelectorAll(body_article);       
                    postItems = [];
                    posts.forEach((item) => {
                        try{
                            if(item.querySelector(article_el)) {
                                // get_article = item.querySelector(article_el).innerText;
                                get_article = item.querySelector(article_el).innerHTML;
                                // get_article = item.querySelector('p').innerText;
                            } else {
                                get_article = item.querySelector('p').innerText;
                            }
                            if(item.querySelector(article_tag_el))
                                get_tag = item.querySelector(article_tag_el).innerText.replace(/\n/g, ",");
                            if(item.querySelector(article_date)) 
                                get_article_date = item.querySelector(article_date).innerText;

                            postItems.push({get_article_date, get_article, get_tag});
                        } catch(e) {}
                    });
                    return postItems;
                }, body_article, article_date, article_el, article_tag_el);

                //console.log(rposts[0].get_article);
                console.log(rposts);
                if(rposts.length > 0) {
                    News.updateArticle(news_id, rposts, function(err, news) {
                        if (err) console.log(err);
                        else console.log({error:false,message:"Article id " +news_id+"  updated successfully!",data:rposts});
                    });
                } else {
                    News.updateErrorArticle(news_id, rposts, function(err, news) {
                        if (err) console.log(err);
                        else console.log({error:false,message:"Article id " +news_id+"  updated successfully!",data:rposts});
                    });
                }
                await browser.close();
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.error(error);
            });

        })();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

exports.article = (err) => {
    News.findNullArticle(function(err, result) {
        // if (err) res.send(err);

        if(result) {
            let article_el, article_tag_el
            Sources.findBySource(result.source, function(err, dt_source) {
                if(dt_source) {
                    let crawl = crawl_article(result.id, result.link, dt_source.all_page_tag, dt_source.body_article, dt_source.article_date,dt_source.article_el, dt_source.article_tag_el);
                }
                // res.json({error:false, article:result, source:dt_source});
            })
        } else {
            // res.send({ error:true, response: "No News return from query" });
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured it out, i just used puppeteer cluster.

Comment: Please do write details about what was the issue and how you solved it so other people can find this useful.